# c# problem with deriving from generic class

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

Below are working classes:

```
public class CatalogManager<T1, T2, T3> where T1 : CatalogDataEntryForm<DataEntryControl>, new()
                                        where T2 : CatalogDataGridForm<DataGridControl>, new()
                                        where T3 : CatalogBusinessObject
{
    public CatalogManager()
    {
        _DataGridFrom = new T2();
        InitGridformToolbarItemeEvents();
    }

}

public class BankDataEntryForm : CatalogDataEntryForm<BankDataEntryControl>
{
}

public class BankDataGridForm : CatalogDataGridForm<BankDataGridControl>
{
}
```

However, below derived class is complaining with error:

```
public class BankManager : CatalogManager<BankDataEntryForm, BankDataGridForm, BankBo>
{
    public BankManager()
    {

    }
}
```

Error message:

> Error CS0311  The type 'BankDataEntryForm' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T1' in the generic type or method 'CatalogManager'. Error   CS0311  The type 'BankDataGridForm' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T2' in the generic type or method 'CatalogManager'

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you're missing a new() in the firstclass...

Comment: `DataEntryControl` is not the same as `BankDataEntryControl`. Learn about covariance.

Comment: http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) as SLaks say `DataEntryControl` is not the same as `BankDataEntryControl`, although They are an inheritance relationship.

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, Visual Basic and C# have keywords that enable you to mark the generic type parameters of interfaces and delegates as covariant or contravariant.

so you can try to make the interface for those class.

- `ICatalogDataEntryForm<out T>` for `CatalogDataEntryForm<T>`
- `ICatalogDataGridForm<out T>` for `CatalogDataGridForm<T>`

then let those class implement interface

```
public interface ICatalogDataEntryForm<out T> 
{ }

public interface ICatalogDataGridForm<out T> 
{ }

public class CatalogDataEntryForm<T> : ICatalogDataEntryForm<T>
{ }
public class CatalogDataGridForm<T> : ICatalogDataGridForm<T>
{}
```

`BankDataGridForm` and `BankDataEntryForm` no need to change.

```
public class BankDataGridForm : CatalogDataGridForm<BankDataGridControl>
{ 
}
public class BankDataEntryForm : CatalogDataEntryForm<BankDataEntryControl>
{
}

public class BankManager : CatalogManager<BankDataEntryForm, BankDataGridForm,CatalogBusinessObject>
{
    public BankManager()
    {

    }
}
```

Then let `CatalogManager` class contract with those interface

```
public class CatalogManager<T1, T2, T3> where T1 : ICatalogDataEntryForm<DataEntryControl>, new()
                                       where T2 : ICatalogDataGridForm<DataGridControl>, new()
                                       where T3 : CatalogBusinessObject
{
    public CatalogManager()
    {

    }

}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dOChvw)